# Null result OnPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, null, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I'm going crazy trying to figure out why this method does not give me the desired result . The method works properly , the toast print the code that I put in the app , when I go to load the cllente pressing the button described in this method , all returns null values ​​. Any idea ?

```
    popupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GetClienteByCodiceCliente task = new GetClienteByCodiceCliente(){
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(ClienteBean clienteBean) {

                    clienteSconto = clienteBean;
                    nomeCliente.setText(clienteBean.getNome() + " " + clienteBean.getCognome());
                    monteVincite.setText(clienteBean.getMonteVincite()+" €");
                    monteScontoCliente.setText(clienteBean.getMonteSconto()+" €");
                    super.onPostExecute(clienteBean);
                }


            };
            TextView codiceCliente = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.codice_cliente);
            String codice = codiceCliente.getText().toString();

            task.execute(codice);
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            String text = "FIND CODE: "+codice;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        }
    });
```

GetClienteByCodiceCliente.class

```
public class GetClienteByCodiceCliente extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, ClienteBean> {

private static final String SERVER_URL = "http://95.110.231.118:8080/TestWSRest/GetClienteByCodiceCliente";

@Override
protected ClienteBean doInBackground(Object... params) {
    ClienteBean cliente = new ClienteBean();
    try {
        Log.d("codiceCliente", params[0].toString());

        String codiceCliente = params[0].toString();
        cliente = getCliente(codiceCliente);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cliente;
}

public ClienteBean getCliente(String codiceCliente) throws Exception {

    ClienteBean cliente = new ClienteBean();

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL);

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
    postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("codiceCliente", codiceCliente));

    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));


    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();

        try {
            //Read the server response and attempt to parse it as JSON
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(content);

            GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
            gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
            cliente = new ClienteBean();
            cliente = gson.fromJson(reader, ClienteBean.class);
            content.close();
            Log.d("jsonResponse", cliente.toString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }else{
        throw new HttpException();
    }
    return cliente;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post your stacktrace? Also, please post your GetClienteByCodiceCliente class.

Comment: After click on button?

Comment: When you say it returns null result, does it crash? If it crashes, please post the error messages so people can help.

Comment: I don't have crashes, but null results on getter ('nomeCliente.setText(clienteBean.getNome() + " " + clienteBean.getCognome());' after click are 'null null')

Comment: What is returning null? Cliente?

Comment: Try logging the values inside the Catch blocks to see what is going on

Comment: `nomeCliente.setText(clienteBean.getNome() + " " + clienteBean.getCognome());` when the button is pressed become `null null`

Answer (score 1):

I think `cliente = gson.fromJson(reader, ClienteBean.class);` sets `cliente` to null then you are returning it.